# An elementary Algebraic Geometry text, similar to Kempf's Algebraic Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Is anyone familiar with an elementary Algebraic Geometry book, which takes a similar approach to that of Kempf's *Algebraic Varieties*, but is more user friendly ?

Comment: Have you looked into Eisenbud and Harris' "Geometry of Schemes"? It doesn't cover cohomology, but except from that, it is a very good book.